# How to find words in Square brackets and convert to dynamic url using php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, regexp-replace

I am trying to find words in Square brackets like this `[word]` and create a dynamic url.

I tried `str_replace()` function to find word, but its creating links like this

```
<a href="search.php?q=">word</a>
```

I cant add searched word into url part:

How can I create a true url like this ?

```
<a href="search.php?q=word">word</a>
```

UPDATED

Here is my fucntion:

```
function findReplace($string){
    $string = str_replace ("[word]", "<a href='search.php?=' title='information'>information</a>", $string); 
    return $string;
}
```

And here is how I get values from database :
`findReplace(htmlspecialchars($row['message']))`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question, it's very messy. Can you please try to improve it?

Comment: Show how you tried `str_replace`.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: I too am having trouble understanding what you're asking.

Comment: please read post updated, I want to find words in Square brackets and make an url from that word.

Comment: Do you want to create url like this based on the match? `<a href="search.php?q=word">word</a>`

Comment: yes that is what I want thanks @marcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is your friend in this case:

```
$longText='bla bla [word1] bla [word2] bla [word3] bla bla';

print preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/', '<a href="search.php?q=$1">$1</a>', $longText);
```

Output:

```
bla bla <a href="search.php?q=word1">word1</a> bla <a href="search.php?q=word2">word2</a> bla <a href="search.php?q=word3">word3</a> bla bla
```

Comment: is it possible if I Have this as a function ? sorry :(

Comment: preg_replace is your function in this case, you just need to use your input string `$row['message']` or whatever.